# What does mean the "permanent" word in the "arp -a" output?

Tags: arp

I'm trying to learn the ARP protocol. My idea about ARP is that it is a protocol that help addressing the IP to the exact MAC Address.

But when I try to do:

```
arp -a
```

Which I think it will show the list of IP addresses and the matching MAC addresses. I understand everything until I see the word `permanent`. The other lines are marked `ifscope`, and one is marked `permanent`.

Can someone tell me what mean `permanent`? Why is this line different?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Arp table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_ARPCaching.htm):

> There are two different ways that cache entries can be put into the
>   ARP cache:
>
> - Static ARP Cache Entries: These are address resolutions that are manually added to the cache table for a device and are kept in the
>     cache on a permanent basis. Static entries are typically managed using
>     a tool such as the arp software utility.
> - Dynamic ARP Cache Entries: These are hardware/IP address pairs that are added to the cache by the software itself as a result of
>     successfully-completed past ARP resolutions. They are kept in the
>     cache only for a period of time and are then removed.

So the word `permanent` in the `arp -a` output means that the entry is manually added to the cache (static).